# 301 redirect subcategory to specific page and redirect rest of site as well

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect a subcategory on a website to a particular page on a new domain and redirect everything else from the old domain to the new domain.

The site redirect I have set up like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I also want to redirect a subcategory on the old site to a particular page on the new site.

For example I would like https://www.old-site,co.uk/category/subcategory (with and without trailing slash at the end) to redirect to https://www.new-site.co.uk/page.htm

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect /category to a specific page on external domain
RewriteRule ^category/?$ http://www.new-domain.com/page.htm [L,R]
#everything else to newdomain
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-site.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear your browser  cache  before testing this.